# AngularJS, ngRepeat, and default checked radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

When using ngRepeat, 3 pairs of radio buttons can be created using the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <input type="radio" name="radio{{i}}" id="radioA{{i}}" value="A" checked> A
    <input type="radio" name="radio{{i}}" id="radioB{{i}}" value="B"> B
</div>
```

For some reason, only the last pair of radio buttons generated by ngRepeat is affected by the `checked` attribute.

Is this because of the way AngularJS updates the view? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is possibly because when browser renders the radio buttons (as ng-repeat expands) all your radios have same name i.e `"name="radio{{i}}"` angular has not expanded it yet, hence the checked property is not applied properly among all of them. So you would need to use [`ng-attr-name`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) so that angular adds expanded name attribute later. So try:-

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="radio{{i}}" ng-attr-id="radioA{{i}}" value="A" checked> A
    <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="radio{{i}}" ng-attr-id="radioB{{i}}" value="B"> B
</div>
```

Or use [`ng-checked="true"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) so that checked attribute is applied as ng-checked directive expands. i.e example

```
<input type="radio" name="radio{{i}}" ng-attr-id="radioA{{i}}" value="A" ng-checked="true"> A
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

  
  <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="radio{{i}}" ng-attr-id="radioA{{i}}" value="A" checked> A
    <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="radio{{i}}" ng-attr-id="radioB{{i}}" value="B"> B
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It should also be noted that, for radio buttons and perhaps other situations, if you're using ngModel, you don't use the checked or ngChecked attributes. Each radio button in a group should have the same ngModel, which contains the value of the radio that should be checked.

Comment: @user3071284 Yup you did not have ng-model in your code.. :)

Comment: Yeah both situations require certain attributes to work out correctly. Your solution fixed one situation I had, and from there, I was able to fix another. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

Here milestone_data.index == selected cat id;

```
 <div  ng-repeat="category in catData.categories" > 
 <input type="radio" name="quality" id="{{category.title}}" ng-value="{{category.id}}" ng-model="milestone_data.index" >
  <span>{{category.title}}</span> 
 </div>
```