# Radio Button and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, radio-button

I know this is a common question on SO, but none of those solve my issue.

This code doesn't allow me to click/select the radio button. And I am unable to see whats wrong. It may bey something simple that I am missing, I'll be glad if someone can help out.

```
<div input-field class="col m6" ng-init="student.username = 0">
<p>Username Generation</p>
<p>
    <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="user" ng-model="student.username" value="0" required />
    <label>Same as Registration ID</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="user" ng-model="student.username" value="1" required />
    <label>Auto Generate</label>
</p>
```

The problem is I cannot select the Radio button, where set in ng-init or not.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/znfvmr80/5/

Comment: Refer this link - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551708/angularjs-ngrepeat-and-default-checked-radio-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551708/angularjs-ngrepeat-and-default-checked-radio-button)

Comment: @MohanP not the same, I am not using ng-repeat. ng-repeat also has its own scope, but then again, no ng-repeat in my code.

Comment: There is problem in css. Remove Css and try to change.

Comment: @MohanP yeah mohan, its due to the way materialize works.

Answer (score 2):

Well the fix was relative easy, and kinda due to me missing out on a `for` attribute. Thanks to @Joyson for helping out, him thinking got me thinking.

This is the correct code:

```
<div input-field class="col m6" ng-init="student_username = 0">
<p>Username Generation</p>
<p>
    <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="user" ng-model="student_username" value="0" required id="same_as_reg" />
    <label for="same_as_reg">Same as Registration ID</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="user" ng-model="student_username" value="1" required id="autogen" />
    <label for="autogen">Auto Generate</label>
</p>
```

Materialize **requires** a `for` attribute label for radio buttons to work.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given is working fine i think you could check more in your js before or after initialization.

Comment: i just made a fiddle. Please see this, same error: https://jsfiddle.net/znfvmr80/

Comment: Angularjs not working properly {{student.username}} please put it in html and check it didnt print anything

Comment: I see that, but i dont know why, TBH i don t use fiddle alot. https://jsfiddle.net/znfvmr80/4/

Comment: I found it. It was missing a `for` for `label` which was required by materialize.css to work with radio. Thanks for taking the time.